# Why is public static method, DragEvent.obtain() not accessible

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, static-methods

Can any one explain why am i not able to access DragEvent.obtain() method.

As per grepcode DragEvent code, method is declared as public static.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/DragEvent.java#DragEvent.obtain%28android.view.DragEvent%29

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not `public` [in the current version of the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/DragEvent.java).

Second, I believe that the "Hide:" you see in the GrepCode entry refers to the `@hide` annotation, which is used by Android when creating the SDK from the source code. Classes and methods marked with `@hide` are not part of the public SDK.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. This explains it.